# Counting the occurence of substrings in matlab

Tags: string, matlab, count

I have a cell, something like this **P= {Face1 Face6 Scene6 Both9 Face9 Scene11 Both12  Face15}**. I would like to count how many Face values, Scene values, Both values in P. I don't care about the numeric values after the string (i.e., Face1 and Face23 would be counted as two). I've tried the following (for the Face) but I got the error "If any of the input arguments are cell arrays, the first must be a cell array of strings and the second must be a character array".

```
strToSearch='Face';
numel(strfind(P,strToSearch));
```

Does anyone have any suggestion? Thank you!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use `regexp` to find strings that start (`^`) with the desired text (such as `'Face'`). The result will be a cell array, where each cell contains `1`  if there is a match, or `[]` otherwise. So determine if each cell is nonempty (`~cellfun('isempty', ...)`: will give a logical `1` for nonempty cells, and `0` for empty cells), and sum the results (`sum`):

```
>> P = {'Face1' 'Face6' 'Scene6' 'Both9' 'Face9' 'Scene11' 'Both12' 'Face15'};
>> sum(~cellfun('isempty', regexp(P, '^Face')))
ans =
     4

>> sum(~cellfun('isempty', regexp(P, '^Scene')))
ans =
     2
```

Comment: Thank you for the answer and the explanation, Luis! Using regexp intimidates me, though.

Comment: That's part of the fun of `regexp` :-) Anyway, this one regular expression is very simple: just the `^` to indicate start

Answer (score 0):

Your example should work with some small tweaks, provided all of P contains strings, but may give the error you get if there are any non-string values in the cell array.

```
P= {'Face1' 'Face6' 'Scene6' 'Both9' 'Face9' 'Scene11' 'Both12' 'Face15'};
strToSearch='Face';
n = strfind(P,strToSearch);
numel([n{:}])
```

(returns 4)